# Here.com (Nokia Api for Maps) : How to manage circles with changing colors on click?

Tags: javascript, here-api

I'm using the Nokia API for my web app (Javascript), and I draw circles in my map with different radium. The thing is when I zoom in, the circle has the same size, which means that when I zoom in, there's a level where I can't see anything else since it covers the whole map. Hence, I want the circle to keep the same size even if I zoom in.

For that, I tried SVG Markers, which solve this problem, but the thing is I had to program when I click on one of them, the color has to change (it's all a mess, and it reduces the performance of the app).

If anyone can help me, that would be awesome !

Answer (score 0):

There are three key points which need to be answered to find a solution your question.

- To add functionality when a marker is clicked, you need to add a **listener** to the **click** event *i.e.*  `marker.addListener("click", function (evt) { ...etc`
- To switch the color of an SVG marker you need two separate icons for that marker. The icon property is **immutable**, and hence it should only be updated using the `set()` method *i.e.* `marker.set("icon", markerIcon);`
- To force a refresh of the screen after the new icon has been set you need to update the map display - `map.update(-1, 0);`

Combining these points togther there is a working example appended below. You need to substitute in your own [app id and token](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_Obtain_Your_Own_Nokia_appID_and_Token) to get it to work of course.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7; IE=EmulateIE9" />
<title>Highlighing a marker: Istanbul (Not Constantinople)</title>
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

<script language="javascript"  src="http://api.maps.nokia.com/2.2.4/jsl.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

</head>
<body>
<p> Click on the marker to change it.</p>
<div id="gmapcanvas"  style="width:600px; height:600px;" >&nbsp;</div><br/><br/>    


<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[    

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Don't forget to set your API credentials
//
// Replace with your appId and token which you can obtain when you 
// register on http://api.developer.nokia.com/ 
//
            nokia.Settings.set( "appId", "YOUR APP ID GOES HERE"); 
            nokia.Settings.set( "authenticationToken", "YOUR AUTHENTICATION TOKEN GOES HERE");

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////   

 map = new nokia.maps.map.Display(document.getElementById('gmapcanvas'), {
     'components': [ 
        // Behavior collection
        new nokia.maps.map.component.Behavior(), 
        new nokia.maps.map.component.ZoomBar()
        ],
    'zoomLevel': 5, // Zoom level for the map
    'center': [41.0125,28.975833] // Center coordinates
});
// Remove zoom.MouseWheel behavior for better page scrolling experience
map.removeComponent(map.getComponentById("zoom.MouseWheel"));


var iconSVG = 
    '<svg width="33" height="33" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">' +
    '<circle stroke="__ACCENTCOLOR__" fill="__MAINCOLOR__" cx="16" cy="16" r="16" />' +
    '<text x="16" y="20" font-size="10pt" font-family="arial" font-weight="bold" text-anchor="middle" fill="__ACCENTCOLOR__" textContent="__TEXTCONTENT__">__TEXT__</text>' +
    '</svg>',
    svgParser = new nokia.maps.gfx.SvgParser(),
    // Helper function that allows us to easily set the text and color of our SVG marker.
    createIcon = function (text, mainColor, accentColor) {
        var svg = iconSVG
            .replace(/__TEXTCONTENT__/g, text)
            .replace(/__TEXT__/g, text)
            .replace(/__ACCENTCOLOR__/g, accentColor)
            .replace(/__MAINCOLOR__/g, mainColor);
        return new nokia.maps.gfx.GraphicsImage(svgParser.parseSvg(svg));
    };

/* On mouse over we want to change the marker's color and text 
 * hence we create two svg icons which we flip on mouse over.
 */
var markerText = "1";

var colors = ["#FF0000", "#00FF00", "#0000FF", "#FFFF00", "#00FFFF", "#FF00FF" , "#000000"];
var markerIcon= createIcon("1", "#F00", "#FFF");

map.addListener("click", function (evt) {
    var target = evt.target;
    if (target instanceof nokia.maps.map.Marker && (target.clickCount === undefined) == false){
        target.clickCount++;
        var icon = createIcon(target.clickCount,  colors[target.clickCount%7], "#FFF");
        target.set("icon", icon);
        map.update(-1, 0);
    }
    if (evt.target instanceof nokia.maps.map.Spatial) {
        evt.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }   
});


var istanbul = new nokia.maps.map.Marker(
    // Geo coordinate of Istanbul
    [41.0125,28.975833], 
    {
        icon: markerIcon,
        clickCount : 1
    }
);

/// Let's add another marker for comparison:
var bucharest = new nokia.maps.map.Marker(
    // Geo coordinate of Bucharest 
    [44.4325, 26.103889], 
    {
        icon: markerIcon,
        clickCount: 1
    }
);



// We add the marker to the map's object collection so it will be rendered onto the map.
map.objects.addAll([istanbul, bucharest]);


// ]]>

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Jason for your reply. I actually did the same thing. But, as I said in my post, the problem is when I have to manage the changing colors (which depends on the number of clicks of the marker, I had to program it). So, I need to know if there's a way pre-implemented in Nokia API that handles all this. Because I did a lot of research, but couldn't find anything. Thank you.

Comment: That you wanted to change the colors on every `click` event was unclear. The structure of the basic example still holds though, but I've amended it to change on each click. To keep the code tidy you should look at [Event Delegation](http://developer.here.com/apiexplorer/examples/api-for-js/events/event-delegation.html) - just create a single function capable of updating any marker, and associate the marker specific data as an additional property.

Comment: BTW don't click on the markers too quickly in the example - I haven't disabled double click zoom.